# attach a google analytics tag / marker / segment to a user when they click on a certain item in an accordion

Tags: google-analytics

**SHORT QUESTION**

How can i attach a google analytics tag / marker / segment to a user when they click on a certain item in an accordion ? Also what would happen if they clicked multiple levels

---

**LONG QUESTION** (with background info)

Ive got a contact us page with an accordion for different enquiry types, as below :

- New projects
- Careers
- Supply & Professionals
- Accounts

Some of these have departments their own contact forms, phone numbers, have emails etc.

What im trying to do is segment traffic in google analytics by a user clicking on a certain items in the accordion, the idea is that i can track leads traffic by users clicking on "New Projects"

How can i attach a google analytics tag / marker / segment to a user when they click on a certain item in an accordion ? Also what would happen if they clicked multiple levels

Answer (score 1):

it is possible.

1) create a event on click of accordion
2) create a segment where event category = eevent category on click of accordion.

Try to capture the text of the accordion in event label so you will be able to differentiate between different clicks